# print recursively the number of files in folders

Tags: bash

I struggled for hours to get this uggly line to work

```
wcr() { find "$@" -type d | while read F; do find $F -maxdepth 0 && printf "%5d " $(ls $F | wc) && printf "$F"; done; echo; }
```

Here is the result

```
39   41  754 ../matlab.sh
1    1   19 ./matlab.sh./micmac
1    1   14 ./micmac
```

My first question is: how can I write it smarter?

Second question: I would like the names printed before the counts but I dont know how to tabulate the outputs, so I cannot do better than this:

```
.
./matlab.sh   1    1   19 
./matlab.sh./micmac    1    1   19
./micmac   1    1   14
```

Comment: Tabulate?  You mean align the columns?  Did you consider that this will look very ugly if just one value in the first column is very long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I don't see what that `find $F -maxdepth 0` shall be good for, so I would just strip it.
2. Also, if a filename contains a `%`, you are in trouble if you use it as the format string to `printf`, so I'd add an explicit format string.  And I combined the two `printf`s.  To switch the columns (see also below for more on this topic), just switch the arguments and adapt the format string accordingly.
3. You should use double quotes around using variables (`"$F"` instead of `$F`) to avoid problems with filenames with spaces or other stuff in them.
4. Then, if a file starts with spaces, your `read` would skip those, rendering the resulting variable useless.  To avoid that, set `IFS` to an empty string for the time of the read.
5. To get only the number of directory entries, you should use option `-l` for `wc` to only count the *lines* (and not also words and characters).
6. Use option `--sort=none` to `ls` to speed up things by avoiding useless sorting.
7. Use option `-b` to `ls` to escape newline characters in file names and thus avoid breaking of counting.
8. Indent your code properly if you want others to read it.

This is the result:

```
wcr() {
  find "$@" -type d | while IFS='' read F
    do
      printf "%5d %s\n" "$(ls --sort=none -b "$F" | wc -l)" "$F"
    done
  echo
}
```

I'd object to switching the columns.  The potentially widest column should be at the end (in this case the path to the file).  Otherwise you will have to live with unreadable output.  But if you really want to do this, you'd have to do two passes:  One to determine the longest entry and a second to format the output accordingly.

Comment: Thank-you for the detailed answers and all the tips.
I find bash scripting much more tricky than any other languages I have learned before. I hope I can get some fluency while practicing.

Comment: Thank-you for the detailed answers and all the tips.
I find bash scripting much more tricky than any other languages I have learned before. I hope I can get some fluency while practicing.

This is why I struggle to get some (kind of) working 'thing' before I seek for help at stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(find . -type d); do
  printf '%-10s %s\n' "$(ls $i | wc -l)" "$i"
done
```

You probably could pre-process the output and use *column* to make some fancier output with whatever order, but since the path can get big, doing this is probably simpler.

Comment: Your command will trip when the directory contains a spacename.

Comment: Thank-you for the 'column' trick. I bookmarked it for later use.